# Installation of Ubuntu 20.04 hung up and had to power off. After powering off, cannot boot into Linux on dual boot PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, 20.04, recovery-mode

For a little while now (6 years) my Lenovo z70 laptop was dual booted with having Windows 10 on one partition and Linux Ubuntu 16.04 on another partion.
Unfortunately, I had to upgrade to 18.04 since 16.04 support ended. I succesfully installed 18.04 on my laptop.
Then, I started upgrading to Linux Ubuntu 20.04. During the final steps of installation the NetworkManager stopped and the installation hung. It was hanging for a little while and I had to power off. So, I powered off midway through installation to discover that i can no longer boot into Linux.

Well, kind of. It looks like when I restart I still get to the boot select screen with my previous options:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.06

*Ubuntu

Advanced options for Ubuntu

Windows UEFI recovery bootmfw.efi

Windows Boot UEFI recovery

EFI/Ubuntu/fwupx64.efi

EFI/Ubuntu/mmx64.efi

Windows UEFI recovery LrsBootmgr.efi

Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)

UEFI Firmware Settings
```

Selecting Ubuntu, as I have before, now goes into infinitely waiting loading screen with "Lenovo" logo.

So, that goes nowhere. Selecting "Advanced options for Ubuntu" gives the following options:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-137-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-137-generic (recovery mode)

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-202-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-202-generic (recovery mode)

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-142-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-142-generic (recovery mode)

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-66-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-66-generic (recovery mode)
```

So, selecting either of the 2 first options (with `5.4.0-137`), also hangs after reaching `[    0.800529] --- [ end Kernel panic -- not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---`

Selecting either of the remaining options actually does go far enough and I reach the "Recovery Menu (filesystem state: read-only)"

This menu has options, which I also all tried.

- resume (Resume normal boot) -> hangs.
- Clean (Try to make free space) -> I have free space
- Dpkg (repair broken packages) -> tool runs, but when trying to boot
  it still hangs.
- failesafeX (Run in fail safe graphic mode) -> terminates with error
  and brings me back to Recovery Menu.
- fsck (Check all file systems) -> runs but terminates prematurely and
  boot still hangs.
- grub (update grub bootloader) -> updated, but booting still hangs.
- network (Enable networking) -> have not tried this.
- root (drop to root shell prompt) -> this works and i can enter the
  root shell. There i can verify my files are there. I think if someone
  can direct me how to either re-install 20.04 or just revert to 18.04
  it would be great. With root shell i verified that I did get 20.04.5
  LTS installed.

Please help me get back into being able to boot my Linux OS. Thanks!

Comment: Make a bootable USB stick with 20.04.5 on another computer. Boot from this device ( on your computer ). If your /home folder is on another partition you can reinstall it directly. If not, make a backup of your files and settings and after that reinstall.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 22.04 is available and will be supported until 2027, just fresh install it instead.